# When I add an element to a java HashSet, all the elements change

Tags: java, hashset

In a Conway's game of life simulator, I have eight blocks of code that look like this to find the neighborhood of a cell.

```
int count = 0;
    p.setLocation(p.x-1, p.y-1); //upper left
    if( data.contains(p) ) ++count;
    else if( addingDeadCells ) {
        deadCellsToCheck.add(p);
        for( Point z : deadCellsToCheck ) 
            System.out.println(z.toString() + " " + z.hashCode()); 
        System.out.println();
    }
```

p is the point representing the current cell, data is a HashSet containing the active cells. For the sake of efficiency I'm only checking dead cells that neighbor live cells, so deadCellsToCheck is another HashSet that starts each generation empty. Each time I execute deadCellsToCheck.add(p), it seems like all the cells already in it get overwritten to be the cell just added, because the output looks like this:

```
java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0] 0

java.awt.Point[x=1,y=0] 1072693248
java.awt.Point[x=1,y=0] 1072693248

java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0] 1073741824
java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0] 1073741824
java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0] 1073741824
etc...
```

I don't think this should be possible for multiple reasons. Any ideas?

Comment: `java.awt.Point` is mutable. I'm willing to bet you are adding the same point to your map over an over.

Comment: Do you ever create a new `Point` object? Or do you just change the existing one? You should create a new `Point` object for every `p` you want to store. Otherwise, you are just changing the existing one (which is what you are seeing). In your case, I believe all the `Point` objects stored in `deadCellsToCheck` are actually the same object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of this problem is that your `HashSet` contains the same instance of `Point` multiple times. Instead of editing the point `p.setLocation(p.x-1, p.y-1);` you should be creating a new one and adding it to the set:

```
int count = 0;
p = new Point(p.x-1, p.y-1); // new point here
if (data.contains(p)) {
     count++;
} else if (addingDeadCells) {
    deadCellsToCheck.add(p);
    for (Point z : deadCellsToCheck)  {
        System.out.println(z.toString() + " " + z.hashCode());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Your current structure also violates contract of `hashCode()` method:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer

The `hashCode` and `equals` methods are used by the set to eliminate duplications. You create point `(0,0)` which has `hashcode = 0`. Then you modify the point to `(1,0)`, its haschode changes to `1072693248` so the set allows to insert this point again. But it is the same instance - it is the same object inserted twice into the set.

Mutable objects generally shouldn't be used in sets or other data structures relying on `hashcode` method.

The solution is to make the point immutable (if you use `java.awt.Point`, I would recommend to create your own class):

```
public class Point {

     private final int x;
     private final int y;

     public Point(int x, int y) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
     }

     // hashcode and equals methods
     // getters and utility methods

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are adding one point to the set over and over again, and altering its value. If you want to add a bunch of different points, you need to make a bunch of new point objects (use the word `new`) instead of just one.